# Trying to insert data from form with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to switch from mysql to PDO and not ure how to go about this I get Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::prepared() in C:\wamp\www\Systems\insert_process.php on line 12 Looking to see if any one can give me a sample or point me in the right direction all tutorials are showing me how to insert data but not with a submit form.

```html
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "systems_requests";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$add_member= $dbh->prepared("INSERT INTO requests(lanId, name, department, manager, request,  request_description, request_comments, status, comments, compUser, compDt) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$add_member->bindParam(1, $_POST["lanId"]);
$add_member->bindParam(2, $_POST["name"]);
$add_member->bindParam(3, $_POST["department"]);
$add_member->bindParam(4, $_POST["manager"]);
$add_member->bindParam(5, $_POST["request"]);
$add_member->bindParam(6, $_POST["request_description"]);
$add_member->bindParam(7, $_POST["request_comments"]);
$add_member->bindParam(8, $_POST["status"]);
$add_member->bindParam(9, $_POST["comments"]);
$add_member->bindParam(10, $_POST["compUser"]);
$add_member->bindParam(11, $_POST["compDt"]);



$dbh->close();

$email = $_POST["emailaddress"]; 

$to = "";
$subject = "Systems Request";
$headers = "From: "; 

$message = "LanID: " . $lanId . " 

" ."User Name: ".  $name ." 

". "Department: " . $department . " 

" ."Manager: ".  $manager . " 

". "User Request: " . $request . "

" ."User Request Description: ".  $request_description .  " 

" ."User Request comments: ".  $request_comments .  "

" ."Status: " .  $status .  " 
 
" ."Systems comments: ".  $comments .  " 
 
" ."Completed by: ".  $compUser ;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 


echo ("<br> <a href='http://a0319p528/dc399Homepage/'> DC399Homepage </a>");
?>
<html>
<body>
<br><br><br>

<h1 align="center">Systems Request Confirmation</h1>
<p align="center">Thank you, <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br><br>
    Your request has been sent. Your request number is <?php echo $id;?><br>
    Please write this number down or print this page out.</p>

<div align="center">
    <h2>Request Information</h2>
    Date Request: <?php $date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s') . "\n";  ?><br>
    Manager: <?php echo $_POST["manager"]; ?><br>
    Location: <?php echo $_POST["department"];  ?><br>
    Request Issue: <?php echo $_POST["request"];  ?> <?php echo $_POST["request_description"];  ?><br>
    Request Comments: <?php echo $_POST["request_comments"];  ?><br>
</div>
<div align="center">
    <h2>Status Information</h2>
    Status: <?php echo $_POST["status"];  ?><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<div align="center"><button onClick="window.print()">Print this page</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does `execute()` come in? *There you go* ;) [**Read the docs**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) edit: and `prepared` remove the `d`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've made an edit without marking it as an edit under your original question.
This is as per [**your originally posted question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26788048/1) should anyone ask why (the answer).

---

It's `prepare` and not `prepared` which is the reason why you're getting the fatal error.

```
$add_member= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO requests ...
```

Plus, you're not executing

add:

```
$add_member->execute();
```

after

```
$add_member->bindParam(11, $_POST["compDt"]);
```

as per the docs

**http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements**

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute(); // <=== right there

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

and

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

---

**Edit** and as per your comment:

> *"I am getting this error now Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp\www\Systems\insert_process.php on line 25"*

You have 11 binds but only 10 values

```
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

add one.

```
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: I am getting this error now Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp\www\Systems\insert_process.php on line 25

Comment: I'll look into it, but first... you've made an edit with the added `execute()` without marking it as an **edit**. People will visit the question and my answer and will say "execute is in there, why the answer"? and stand at being downvoted because of it. Always mark your code/question as an "added" edit under your original post. @Donny

Comment: @Donny Reload my answer and near the bottom under **Edit**.

Comment: @Donny So Donny, how you coming along?

Comment: I was able to get it to work. Now I just got to get the email part to work.

Comment: @Donny That's great Donny, I'm glad to hear it.

Comment: @Donny Try posting a new question with just the mail codes, I may be able to help you, or others as well.

Comment: I will if i get stuck I think I may have it not sure yet. Also I am trying to do an update page that might be posted for a question for sure

Comment: @Donny Ok Donny, if and once I see it, I'll see what I can do, and many others stand at seeing it also. By hook or by crook, we'll get 'er done ;)

Comment: Nice to demonstrate how named placeholders makes this a whole lot less messy.

Comment: Yes indeed @tadman and easier to track/keep tabs on than question marks.

Answer (score 4):

The right method name is [prepare](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php), so change to:

```
$add_member= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO requests(lanId, name, department, manager, request,  request_description, request_comments, status, comments, compUser, compDt) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: Good catch on that, but it's missing another essential part.

Comment: I fixed that part prepare. no errors now just no data in the database when I insert. probably from missing excute() statement do you know where i put that in is it after the last bindParam. Then now I have to declare variables for my email function to work at the bottom part.

Comment: @Donny, Fred -ii- answer is very detalhed, following his instructions i think you will reach a solution

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Your answer is very nice, my congrats!

Comment: @MarcioSimao Thank you Marcio. I will +1 yours. I on my side have reached my daily points cap (*not making extra points*) and only 2 votes left lol *Cheers*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789494/trying-update-record-with-pdo I posted the question for update here. I am little lost on what to do is it the same as insert

Comment: @Donny, Okay, i will take a look

Comment: It is a mess I need to try redo and figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to prepare fuction to build sql query and once query is ready or built properly it will execute and produce results.